# Curl to API endpoint with MongoDB return two difference values from the same query

Tags: php, mongodb

My API return diferences values, when the document has "refinanciamento" on the value, the consumption of the content return error. When is another value for the document, has success! I'm brazilian, my english is bad, sorry.

The var_dump success print resume:
"query":"{"CPStatus":"Indivíduo fez opt-in do Cadastro Positivo","Segment":"CPF contém somente negativações ativas, seguido de dados positivos", ...

This is correct!

The var_dump error print resume:
"query":""{\"CPStatus\":\"Indivíduo fez opt-in do Cadastro Positivo\",\"Segment\":\"CPF contém somente negativações resolvidas\", ...

How can i change for what the endpoint consumption has successfuly?

Actually i dont have endpoint access... And the curl is correct, because is very simple (have url, return transfer and hash).

Thanks!

My API return diferences values, when the document has "refinanciamento" on the value, the consumption of the content return error. When is another value for the document, has success!